# I need an equvalent to Noteshelf for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a new Ubuntu user, and i am searching for the equivalent of Noteshelf  for Ubuntu it does not have to be freeware it has to be as close as possible to Noteshelf that is I need it for college...

Any Ideas? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I tried MyScript Stylus : http://www.visionobjects.com/fr/webstore/myscript-stylus/description/

There is also tegaki-recognize and cellwriter `sudo apt-get install tegaki-recognize` or `sudo apt-get install cellwriter` but those are very simple